# How to call a worksheet function which is a method of a class

Tags: google-apps-script, worksheet-function, custom-function

Issue

I have a method inside a class like this:

```
class WorksheetFunctions {
  DrivingDistance(destination, origin) {
    return App.Maps.getDrivingMiles(destination, origin);
  }
}
```

and I want to call that from a worksheet cell. Previously `function DrivingDistance(destination, origin)` was in the global area as a stand-alone function, and worked fine.

Now I try:

```
=WorksheetFunctions.DrivingDistance("valid address","valid address")
```

and I get the `#NAME?` error. I can do `=WorksheetFunctions()` with no error, but that's not very useful.

I'm hoping there's a way with apostrophes or brackets or something, that I can get around the formula error.

My motivation is to clean up the global namespace.

I have tried

```
='WorksheetFunctions.DrivingDistance'("valid address","valid address")
```

and `=[WorksheetFunctions.DrivingDistance]("valid address","valid address")`

and neither one of those worked.

Comment: At the custom function, it is required to recognize as the function with `for (let i in this) if (typeof this[i] == "function") console.log(i)`. In this case, `const sample = () => "ok"` can be used as `=sample()`. But it seems that `this.sample = () => "ok"` cannot be used as `=sample()`. When the latter is used, that the Class can be used for the custom menu. But that cannot be used for the custom function. I thought that in the current stage, these might be related to is the reason of your issue. So I thought that your workaround makes sense. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, thank you! is your comment referring to `CustomFunction(functionName, ...args)`, or is it referring to my main question?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that `CustomFunction(functionName, ...args)` makes sense and is suitable for this situation.

Comment: Hello @toddmo, if Tanaike's indications were useful to you, could you post the solution as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Jescanellas, I edited my question to remove the work-around since it has been a 100% distraction to my actual issue.